# Any way to remove “adding finishing details” post processing on Windows 10 Camera app?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia, apps, camera, system-apps

I wanna ask is there any of you here know any hack, Interop app tools tweaks or any settings, even on when you’re only Interop Unlocked or jailbroken your Windows phone to disable that pesky “Adding finishing details” which is basically post processing the images, not just ruins it but also slows the process of taking pictures. Because of that, you’ll end up with “Saving…” message on your Windows 10 Camera app on 10 pictures straight you taken, you can’t take unlimited pictures.

[Here’s some pictures](https://imgur.com/a/Ag4vi) to tell you how it really ruins the pictures. The first every photo is what after the photo is taken, the post processing is still loaded, but basically a screenshot of the screen. It’s almost as good as what really the camera is seeing. The second ones are after the post processing.

Btw. I’m using a Lumia 830 and the very latest build available for it. Yes I got the most recent and latest Camera app update on mine, I dunno but I really think an app update after are what starts ruining the images here, I’m really sure this “Finishing details” aint here before Microsoft implemented this half bakedly, my phone aint shooting pictures this bad. The camera aint that really bad, it’s just the post processing that ruins it. It’s annoying and unacceptable. I can’t file this on Feedback Hub and ask for a fix, since I can’t get any newer updates since Insider Preview ditched my model already on Insider Preview. So please help me fix this the hard way.

**Please help me remove this pesky process if it’s possible. I don’t’ want to use a third party app** since no other 3rd party camera app has integration with Photos app, aint got Panorama feature, **and I don’t want to screenshot every other photo I’ve taken after just to preserve that details.**

Comment: To me, the "after" pictures have a better white balance adjustment (which also matches my experience with this step) - what do you think is wrong about them?

Comment: I think it's getting more darker, I like higher saturation of it before the post process. Especially on the selfies, it's ridiculous because it shows you a possible much better version it, then it's process hogs the phones which you can't take so many pictures.

Comment: Have you tried turning off the HDR feature?